# Calling the normal function of "this"

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, `this` depends on the function call method.

1. Calling General Functions
2. Method Call
3. Call constructor function
4. arrow function call, etc.

but in this case

```js
class Numbers {
  numberArray = [];

  multiply(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      this.numberArray.push(item * item);
    });
  }
}

const numbers = new Numbers();

numbers.multiply([1, 2, 3]);
```

If you look at the fourth line in this class example,

Since `arr.forEach` is calling a callback function with `this`, I think the `arr` is a `this` but Why does `this` means `undefined`?

I don't know why it's a general function call.

Comment: Well, `this` in the forEach callback has a new context, you need to pass the context of multiply to your callback. Just assign the `this` to a variable and use it in forEach callback or use the arrow function.

Comment: The `.forEach()` method is being invoked with a context of `arr`, but the callback itself isn't being called with `arr` as the context, instead, JavaScript is invoking the callback. Usually that will mean that the `this` defaults to the global object, such as the `window` in browsers. However, in "strict mode", it will default to `undefined`. Since classes run in strict-mode by default, the callback for the `forEach` will have a `this` of `undefined`.